# How can I get photos from my DSLR (with a CF card) to my iPad wirelessly?

Tags: ipad, data-synchronization, photos

I can shot tethered to my MBP (using LR3) but then how do I get them to the iPad wirelessly or better yet bypass the MBP altogether?  I know they have a wifi card for SD cameras but my dslr only uses CF cards.

Comment: You might be better of asking this question on http://photo.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

You have a variety of choices!

Without using the MBP:

1. A iPad card reader such as http://photojojo.com/store/awesomeness/ipad-cf-sd-reader/ (not supported by Apple) for CF cards.
2. If your DSLR has a USB port, get the Apple Camera Connection Kit and plug in your camera via USB.

   This *may not* work, depending on your camera. It needs to support either Mass Storage Device or Picture Transfer Protocol. The older your camera, the less likely it is to support these transfer options. I recommend trying a connection kit belonging to a friend or a friendly shop first.
3. Get an SD-CF adaptor for your camera, a SD card, and the Camera Connection Kit.
4. Get an SD-CF adaptor for your camera, a Eye-Fi brand WiFi SD card, and their free iPad app.

Using the MBP:

1. Get an SD-CF adaptor for your camera, a WiFi SD card, the latest iPhoto and sync via iCloud.
2. Tether your camera to your MBP, and use the latest iPhoto to sync via iCloud.

Answer (score -1):

There are compact flash card readers for the iPad that plug into the dock connector

Just Google iPad cf card reader for them

Answer (score -1):

I use an app called [Portfolio](http://ipadportfolioapp.com/) which comes with Portfolio Loader for Mac.

The Mac app is used to select folders of images
The iPad app acts as a photo library.